# SSDs same bandwidth as HDDs now? (2018)

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

I am looking at different storage options for a new server. I've noticed that both HDDs and SSDs claim 6Gb/s throughput:

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?item=N82E16822232558

https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA8TK78R3891

Assuming that the workloads will be sequential access, is really true that the HDDs could work at the same speed as SSDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re confusing the capabilities of the hardware interface with the capabilities of the hardware.

Just because you have a garden hose that can move a 100 gallons a minute, doesn’t mean you have a pump to produce a 100 gallons a minute. That’s my technical explanation.

Look at iops, seek and transfer times and rates between the various drives. Interface specifications are really not important here. Unfortunately, the information is limited to what the manufacturer provides.

https://www.wdc.com/content/dam/wdc/website/downloadable_assets/eng/spec_data_sheet/2879-800074.pdf

- Host to/from drive (sustained): 225 MB/s

https://www.micron.com/parts/solid-state-storage/ssd/mtfddak2t0tbn-1ar1zab

- Sequential Read: 530MB/s
- Sequential Write: 500MB/s

Looking only at sequential transfer you can see the SSD is more than double of the HDD. However, where SSD's absolutely kill the HDD is with seek times. Where it is measured in microseconds for SSDs and milliseconds for HDDs. The HDD will be many magnitudes slower than an SSD which is nearly instantaneous.

Long story short an SSD will seriously outperform any HDD.